# If the electron has no spatial dimensions based on QM, does not it violate the Planck length as the minimum admissible length for physical entities?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electrons, length

I think the question is self-explanatory: Quantum mechanics insists that electrons have no dimensions as point-like entities, while there is a minimum (non-zero) boundary for length called the Planck length.

Comment: *there is a minimum (non-zero) boundary for length called the Planck length* Not in any widely-accepted theory.

Answer (score 2):

We don't have a working theory at Planck length right now. Therefore we cannot make any statement of the size or structure of an electron.

On the other hand we've explored length scales down to $10^{-16}-10^{-17}$m. The Planck length is 14 orders of magnitude smaller than the smallest length which could be explored by temporary physics.
At scales of $10^{-16}-10^{-17}$m the electron behaves as a point particle.

In difference to the protron which has a structure at $10^{-14}-10^{-15}$m. In particular in deep inelastic scattering the non-pointlike behaviour of the proton could be observed. For the time being nothing comparable has been observed for the electron down to $10^{-16}-10^{-17}$m. If we could explore length scales of $10^{-31}$m we would probably see something for the electron. But temporary physics is very very far from that.

Physics is actually very scale dependent: On different scales we observe different physics. So at $10^{-16}-10^{-17}$m we observe actual Quantum field theory where an electron is considered as pointlike. And this theory works very well in its range of application.

Certainly at $10^{-31}$m we would see something different. But what it is we still do not know.

Comment: A good answer it is. I think what you mean is that any useful measurement cannot be made '**across**' the electron as long as electron is considered pointlike. When it is considered wavelike, Planck length is the ultimate lower limit for measurement.

Comment: @Proscionexium A measurement does not depend on a assumption respectively a model. A measurement is what your measurement devices tell you. Think of the proton: assume that it is pointlike, then you make an experiment which tells you that it is not pointlike.  How to check experimentally out if a particle has a structure a Planck length is a complete different question.

Comment: Actually I heard that by the time we reach Planck length, the uncertainty principle would imply so large energy that space-time would be severely distorted to measure even a little greater than the Planck length.

Comment: @Proscionexium The question was: Why do we assume that the electron is pointlike ? Because we have no indication, i.e. measurement that proves the contrary. What happens at the Planck length is pure speculation how fascinating it might be. May be we will never know with certainty what at Planck length happens.

Answer (score 2):

We have no actual evidence that the Planck length is a minimum. All of our current best theories of the universe (quantum field theory and general relativity) treat spacetime as continuous. There are some speculative suggestions that spacetime might be discrete at the Planck scale, and those speculations for some reason get a lot of attention in the pop-sci press. But they are just speculation at this point, without any evidence. Whenever the idea of a minimum length has been subjected to experiment (e.g. tests of "doubly special relativity") the experiments have come out against a minimum length and in favor of continuous spacetime.